# В чем практическая польза FOREIGN KEY в таблицах MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Не понимаю в чем практическая польза `FOREIGN KEY` для таблиц. Например, у меня есть три таблицы:

```
Users {user_id, name, surname}
Orders {order_id, user_id, invoice_id}
Invoices {invoice_id, summ}
```

Логично использовать `user_id` и `invoice_id` как внешние ключи из соответствующих таблиц Users и Invoices. На сколько я понимаю, назначение `user_id` и `invoice_id` внешними ключами не позволит мне сделать ошибку и добавить в таблицу `Orders` заказ с несуществующими значениями `user_id` и `invoice_id`.

На это практическая польза `FOREIGN KEY` заканчивается? У меня по этому поводу сомнения.

Как еще я должен использовать `FOREIGN KEY`?

Я могу представить, если бы у меня в таблице `Orders` было поле `name`, значение которого автоматически обновляется, если изменяется его значение в родительской таблице. В этом бы была польза, но мне кажется не верно создавать дублирующиеся поля в разных таблицах... Поэтому я пытаюсь понять, как используются `FOREIGN KEY`?

Comment: Не у верен за MySql, но в других СУБД поддерживаются конструкции вида `on delete cascade` и т.д.

Comment: Контроль ссылочной целостности основное и единственное назначение внешних ключей. И да, как заметил @Viktorov дополнительно внешние ключи могут каскадно удалять записи при удалении из родительской таблицы или выставлять ссылки в NULL (если их об этом попросить). Но в общем то это одна из разновидностей контроля целостности. НО этого единственного их назначения более чем достаточно, БД без контроля ссылок очень быстро приходит в противоречивое состояние и после этого невозможно разобраться откуда что взялось

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснения. Напишите, пожалуйста, ответ и я его приму.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FOREIGN KEY** используется для ограничения по ссылкам.
Когда все  значения в одном поле таблицы представлены в поле другой таблицы, говорится, что первое поле ссылается на второе. Это указывает на прямую связь между значениями двух полей.

Когда одно поле в таблице ссылается на другое, оно называется внешним ключом, а поле на которое оно ссылается, называется родительским ключом. Имена внешнего ключа и родительского ключа не обязательно должны быть одинаковыми. Внешний ключ может иметь любое число полей, которые все обрабатываются как  единый  модуль. Внешний ключ и родительский ключ, на который он ссылается,  должны иметь одинаковый номер и тип поля,  и находиться в одинаковом порядке. Когда поле является внешним ключом, оно определенным образом связано с таблицей, на которую он ссылается. Каждое значение, (каждая строка ) внешнего ключа должно недвусмысленно ссылаться к одному и только этому значению (строке) родительского ключа. Если это условие соблюдается, то база данных находится в состоянии ссылочной целостности.

**SQL** поддерживает  ссылочную целостность с ограничением **FOREIGN KEY**. Эта функция должна ограничивать значения, которые  можно  ввести в базу данных, чтобы заставить внешний ключ и родительский ключ соответствовать принципу  ссылочной целостности. Одно из действий ограничения **FOREIGN KEY** — это отбрасывание значений для полей, ограниченных как внешний ключ, который еще не представлен в родительском ключе. Это ограничение также воздействует на способность изменять или удалять значения родительского ключа

Ограничение **FOREIGN KEY** используется в команде **CREATE TABLE** (или **ALTER TABLE** (предназначена для модификации структуры таблицы), содержащей поле, которое объявлено внешним ключом. Родительскому ключу дается имя, на которое  имеется ссылка внутри ограничения **FOREIGN KEY**.

Подобно большинству ограничений, оно может быть ограничением таблицы или столбца, в форме таблицы позволяющей использовать многочисленные поля как один внешний ключ.

Пример: есть две таблицы users и emails:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)

CREATE TABLE sys.emails (
  email_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email_address varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (email_id)
)
```

Между ними есть зависимость в виде users.user_id и emails.user_id, и мы хотим что в поле emails.user_id не смогло записываться ничего кроме значения с таблицы users столбец user_id, для этого и создаем ограничение в виде внешнего ключа:

```
ALTER TABLE emails 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
  REFERENCES users (user_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Допустим если мы удаляем пользователя то и автоматически удаляем все записи связанные с ним, в данном случае его адрес электронной почты.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. С простым каким-то примером было бы легче отследить смысл.

Answer (score 0):

В MySQL 3.23.44 и выше в таблицах InnoDB осуществляется проверка ограничений целостности внешних ключей

Фактически для соединения двух таблиц внешние ключи не нужны.

Единственное, что MySQL в настоящее время не осуществляет (в типах таблиц, отличных от InnoDB), это проверку (CHECK) что ключи, которые вы используете, действительно существуют в таблице(ах) на которые вы ссылаетесь, и не удаляет автоматически записи из таблиц с определением внешних ключей.